# Is there a way to use text-to-speech without a third party program?

Tags: text-to-speech

I like using my Macintosh to read things, but Ubuntu is really growing on me. I want to be able to have my computer read aloud to me without booting up my Mac. 
Is there a way to do this without installing any third party programs?

If not, could you reccomend something as light weight as possible? Some of the answers I found involved running the program at start-up. I'd prefer not to have the program running until I want to use it.

Comment: You should see more at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/TextToSpeech

Comment: There is a screen reader installed by default. Is that not good enough?

Comment: I didn't realize that muru. Thanks, I will look into the default one. I searched, but I guess I wasn't using the right key words.

Comment: How do you want to read things? Which kind of interface? Are the built-in tools doing what you need? If not, please explain with more details what you are looking for.